# Inputting elements of unknown type into a vector

Tags: c++, types, vector

I'm working on a program that takes elements from a user and sorts them. For this program, I have to use a vector as the size of the element list is unknown prior to user input. Our instructions were:

> Write a program in C++ to implement sorting of a list of elements.
>   Elements can be of any type but will all be of same type, like all
>   integers or all floats or all chars or all strings (strings shall be
>   sorted like in a dictionary). You can implement any sorting algorithm
>   of your choice.
>
> 1. Ask the user how many elements will be there
> 2. Ask the user to input elements
> 3. Ask the user to choose the sorting order: ascending or descending or both
> 4. Print both input and output lists
> 5. User will not provide any information regarding the type of elements

I'm not very familiar with vectors (teacher basically skimmed topic in class) and my book isn't giving me a whole lot of information on the subject. The problem I'm running into is that I don't know the type of the element list until the user begins input. So far, I have tried:

- creating a void type vector (obviously not allowed now that I've researched it, oops)
- overloading a function called `insertInVector` by sending the first element to the function and letting the function determine which vector type to create based on the type of the first element (which seemed like my best option when I thought of it, except I need access to the vector after the function terminates, so that ended up being a no go, too)
- `#include <typeinfo>` in program, finding the type of the first element, and then
  creating a vector using `vector<typeid(firstElement).name()>` and honestly I'm not
  sure why that didn't work, but it didn't.

Like I said I have EXTREMELY limited experience with vectors as this is my first time using them. I'm also a fairly new programmer so a lot of the research I've done on this has gone over my head. Any help that could be given in this would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I think you could use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/any.html). The template argument needs to be passed at compile time.

Comment: are all the elements of the same type, or can the user insert elements of different types during the same program execution?

Comment: The elements all have to be of the same type when entered by the user

Comment: And how do you determine what the type is based on the input?

Comment: `vector<void>` is not allowed... `vector<void*>` is. And actually the whole requirement seems a bit odd are you sure this is the best way to approach? And is this homework?

Comment: Yes, this is homework. I am not sure this is the best way to approach, no. My teacher tends to give very broad instructions for assignments

Comment: Our instructions were: 

Write a program in C++ to implement sorting of a list of elements. Elements can be of
any type but will all be of same type, like all integers or all floats or all chars or all strings (strings
shall be sorted like in a dictionary). You can implement any sorting algorithm of your choice.
1. Ask the user how many elements will be there
2. Ask the user to input elements
3. Ask the user to choose the sorting order: ascending or descending or both
4. Print both input and output lists
5. User will not provide any information regarding the type of elements

Comment: `Yes, this is homework.` Then you should add the homework tag to your question

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't aware that mattered... at all. My problem isn't just completing a homework assignment, it's understanding the concepts behind what my homework is using

Comment: @Monique: in general it matters in how we answer the question. For homework you are more likely to get hints (so that you can figure things out on your own) and more details on the underlying concepts (because we don't assume you know much already).

Answer (score 5):

C++ is a language *statically* typed. It means that all the types should be determined during compilation: you cannot introduce new types when running the program.

> - creating a void type vector (obviously not allowed now that I've researched it, oops)

`void` is actually quite a strange type, mostly a placeholder for when you would expect a type (like a function return type) and have none to provide. `void*` is used as a pointer to an unknown type (mostly in C) but this is quite a hack, because the information about the original is discarded (as far as the language is concerned) so this causes issues to actually do things with the value so obtained.

> - overloading a function called insertInVector by sending the first element to the function and letting the function determine which vector type to create based on the type of the first element
> - `#include <typeinfo>` in program, finding the type of the first element, and then creating a vector using `vector<typeid(firstElement).name()>` and honestly I'm not sure why that didn't work, but it didn't.

Unfortunately neither is possible: since you cannot declare a variable without a type, what would be the type of `firstElement` to begin with ?

---

The problem you are describing is difficult in general. Basically it means that you will have to accept a string of characters, and then code a set of rules to determine how to interpret those characters. This is done generically by using a *grammar* to encode those rules; but grammars might way complicated for what is probably a simple task.

Let me put together a small example:

```
class Input {
public:
    enum Type {
        Int,
        Double,
        String
    };

    static Input Parse(std::string const& s);

    Input(): _type(Int), _int(0), _double(0.0) {} // need to define a default...

    Type type() const { return _type; }

    int asInt() const {
        assert(_type == Int && "not an int");
        return _int;
    }

    double asDouble() const {
        assert(_type == Double && "not a double");
        return _double;
    }

    std::string const& asString() const {
        assert(_type == String && "not a string");
        return _string; 
    }

private:
    Type _type;
    int _int;
    double _double;
    std::string _string;
};
```

Obviously, the real challenge is to correctly `Parse` the input.

The idea is to use a set of rules, for example:

- an `int` is composed exclusively of digits, optionally prefixed by `-`
- a `double` is composed exclusively of digits, with at most one `.` and optionally prefixed by `-`
- a `string` can be anything, therefore is our catch-all

Then we can write the recognition part of the `Parse` method:

```
static bool isInt(std::string const& s) {
    if (s.empty()) { return false; }
    
    // The first character may be among digits and '-'
    char const first = s.at(0);
    if (not isdigit(first) and first != '-') { return false; }

    // Subsequent characters may only be digits
    for (char c: s.substr(1)) {
        if (not isdigit(c)) { return false; }
    }

    // Looks like it is an int :)
    return true;
} // isInt

// Note: any int could be interpreted as a double too
static bool maybeDouble(std::string const& s) {
    if (s.empty()) { return false; }

    // The first character may be among digits, '.' and '-'
    char const first = s.at(0);
    if (not isdigit(first) and first != '.' and first != '-') { return false; }

    // There may only be one dot
    bool hasSeenDot = s.at(0) == '.';

    // Subsequent characters may only be digits and a dot now
    for (char c: s.substr(1)) {
        if (not isdigit(c) and c != '.') { return false; }

        if (c == '.') {
            if (hasSeenDot) { return false; } // no second dot allowed
            hasSeenDot = true;
        }
    }

    // Looks like it could be a double
    return true;
} // maybeDouble

static Input::Type guessType(std::string const& s) {
    if (isInt(s)) { return Input::Int; }

    // Test double after we ensured it was not an int
    if (maybeDouble(s)) { return Input::Double; }

    return Input::String;
} // guessType
```

And with the guessing logic together, finally the parse comes:

```
Input Input::Parse(std::string const& s) {
    Input result;

    result._type = guessType(s);

    switch(result._type) {
    case Input::Int: {
        std::istringstream stream(s);
        s >> result._int;
        return result;
    }
    case Input::Double: {
        std::istringstream stream(s);
        s >> result._double;
        return result;
    }
    case Input::String:
        result._string = s;
        return result;
    }

    // Unreachable (normally)
    abort();
} // Input::Parse
```

Phew!

So ? Almost there. Now we need to determine how to compare two inputs. It's easy if they all have the same type, if not you will need to determine an arbitrary logic. You can transform an input Int in an input Double easily enough, but for string it's a bit weirder.

```
// define < for comparing two instance of "Input",
// assuming they both have the same type
bool operator<(Input const& left, Input const& right) {
    assert(left.type() == right.type() && "Different Types!");

    switch(left.type()) {
    case Input::Int: return left.asInt() < right.asInt();
    case Input::Double: return left.asDouble() < right.asDouble();
    case Input::String: return left.asString() < right.asString();
    }
} // operator<
```

And finally, the program:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // parse command line
    std::vector<Input> inputs;

    // by convention argv[0] is the program name, it does not count!
    for (int i = 1; i != argc; ++i) {
        inputs.push_back(Input::Parse(argv[i]));

        // Detect that the type is the same as the first input
        if (inputs.size() >= 2) {
            if (inputs.back().type() != inputs.front().type()) {
                std::cerr << "Please only use one type among Int, Double and String\n";
                return 1; // non-0 is an error
            }
        }
    }

    // sort
    std::sort(inputs.begin(), inputs.end());

    // echo back to the user
    for (Input const& i: inputs) {
        switch(i.type()) {
        case Input::Int: std::cout << i.asInt() << "\n"; break;
        case Input::Double: std::cout << i.asDouble() << "\n"; break;
        case Input::String: std::cout << i.asString() << "\n"; break;
        }
    }

    // End of the program
    return 0;
}
```

Of course as I don't know the types you wish to deal with.. I've decided an arbitrary set ;) However this should give you a skeleton to base yourself on.

Comment: That's a great answer. The only bit I don't like of this design is that it's a bit greedy in terms of memory requirements, but I guess it doesn't matter in her case.

Comment: This is a great answer, but apparently the point of the assignment was to implement a sorting algorithm, so I'd personally remove the recommendation to use `std::sort`.  Nonetheless +1 for the detail (and it *does* address OP's issues).

Comment: Never heard of `boost::variant`? That would be much more ideal than writing your own. Also, you forgot the `break` statements on the switch.

Comment: This seems like overkill, as the _only_ place you need the types at all is the comparison function.

Comment: @DeadMG: Thanks for the `break`. As for `boost::variant` => not suitable for the OP level I fear; we are talking about a beginner still strugling with the concepts of static typing.

Comment: @Matthieu: Which is exactly why he needs to get started with the good stuff, not the hacky hand-rolled awful.

Comment: @DeadMG: then we will have to agree to disagree. **I** think `boost::variant` and the concept of static visitation are way too complicated (way too much boilerplate) for the task at hand.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the actual requirements of the problem as stated in the comments, I suggest you store all the inputs in an `std::vector<std::string>` and sort the vector using [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). So, instead of worrying about different types, you can specify the sorting logic depending on what you interpret the strings in your vector to represent. So

1. Implement sorting functions for strings depending on what the strings represent (more later)
2. store inputs as strings in a vector.
3. Determine which type the strings represent
4. select the sorting function based on this type
5. Sort the vector using `std::sort` and the appropriate sort function.

Concerning the sorting function, `std::sort` accepts a binary functor or function that applies a "less-than" comparison to two elelemts, so your functors or functions should look something like

```
bool foo(const std::string& rhs, const std::string& lhs) {
  // implement the logic
}
```

**Edit**: Looking at more recent comments, it seems that the main purpose if the exercise might have been to implement sorting algorithms for different types. In that case, I would suggest following the approach taken by the C++ standard library, that is, to implement sorting in terms or a *less-than* comparison between two types, thereby decoupling the sorting logic from the types to be sorted. So you would want a template sorting function, templated on iterator type and comparison function/functor.

Comment: lexicographic order is different from numerical order.

Comment: @akappa the sorting logic can be specified.

Comment: @juanchopanza Don't you think that "You can implement any sorting algorithm of your choice" implies that they have to write their own algorithm as opposed to using `std::sort`?

Comment: @Fraser probably. I am struggling to identify the real point of the exercise.

Comment: @Fraser: or they can specify a 3rd argument when calling `std::sort`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah - I'm kinda suspicious that the teacher meant the point of the exercise to be implementing a sorting algorithm, but inadvertently made the hardest part creating the container.

Comment: @Fraser yes, implementing a sorting function is one of those classic CS assignments.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Does that count as implementing a sorting algorithm?  Guess it's up to the teacher's interpretation.

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right, the point of the exercise was to implement a sorting algorithm -_- unfortunately he's not experienced in teaching (graduate student) and didn't go in depth in vectors because they are actually not supposed to be covered until a later chapter...they were merely introduced briefly up till now, but I don't think he realizes this.

Comment: @Monique In which case, I'd recommend either this or MatthieuM's answer, but replacing `std::sort` with your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Monique: so he intertwined an algorithmic task with a design one (and pretty advanced in that regard)? He must be banned from teaching.

Comment: @akappa: or perhaps just shown a better way, one would hope that a real teacher would design the courses to be covered :/

Answer (score 1):

If you know what are the types the user may input, you can use templates and inheritance:

```
class Generic {
public:
  virtual void process_input() = 0; // Handles the next input from user
  virtual void process_output() = 0; // Processes the data inserted
};

template <typename T>
class HandleInput : public Generic {
private:
    std::vector<T> storage;
public:
    HandleInput(T first)
    {
      storage.push_back(first);
    }

    void process_input()
    {
      // do whatever you want
    }

    void process_output()
    {
      // do whatever you want
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Get first input
  Input i = input();
  Generic *g;

  // Instantiate the "right" generic with a switch
  switch (i.type) {
    case T:
      g = new HandleInput<T>(i.value);
  }

  // Use Generic from here onwards
}
```

That's just an idea (`Input` cannot be implemented like that, you need to change that part with the logic that gets something from the user and determines its type), but it has the benefit of masking the type into a generic class, so you can factor your code around the interface provided by `Generic`.

Another idea (easier, probably) is using a `std::vector<void*>` and an `enum` that tells you what the type of the data stored in the vector is. When you need to process that data somewhere in the future, you can switch on the enum to appropriately cast the vector elements to the correct type and dispatch them to the appropriate code.

**EDIT**: another idea is to define a templatized function that takes the input and sorts the array using standard comparators:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

template <typename T>
void print_v(std::vector<T> &v)
{
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator it;
    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void sort_and_print(T first, size_t n, bool asc)
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    v.push_back(first);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::string s;
        std::cin >> s;
        T e = boost::lexical_cast<T>(s);
        v.push_back(e);
    }

    print_v(v);
    if (asc)
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<T>());
    else
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    print_v(v);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string s = "test";
    sort_and_print(s, 2, true);
    unsigned int j = 3;
    sort_and_print(j, 2, true);
    return 0;
}
```

The logic to determine the type of the first input is up to you (maybe you can open another question) ;)

Comment: I am afraid that you are going way too far from what the OP understands. He still has not integrated the idea of static typing and you are already up in templates. (Not to say that the response is too bad, just that I am afraid it's beyond his grasp)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: maybe, but I don't know how she could came up with something more easy which doesn't involve `boost` or something more sophisticated (except using a vector of `void*`, maybe, but I am not sure that losing the type could lead to something useful).

Comment: @akappa, that looks like it might work but Matthieu is right, it's a little over my head. One of the main problems I'm dealing with, also, is that I don't know how to determine the type of the input I get from the user. I know how to use functions like `isdigit` to distinguish between a char and a number, but beyond that I'm clueless =\

Comment: @Monique: your efforts to abstract away the details is lovely and indeed a good practice, but I suspect that the details on what types you could get from the input and how you are supposed to distinguish them could be indeed useful.

Comment: But how does the switch work? You seem to be using a type for the case, whihc requires a constant expression.

Comment: I agree, the thing is I'm not trying to abstract away the details, I'm just not sure how to FIND the details. I am not allowed to ask the user for input on the types, and I'm at a loss to distinguish them beyond that

Comment: @Monique: do you know something about templates?

Comment: @juanchopanza: read the comments below the code, it is just a kind of pseudocode showing an idea

Comment: @akappa, not a lot. I'm in the same boat with templates as I am with vectors- my teacher taught the basic concept but not much more. I'm also the type of person that learns really well from examples and working with stuff directly, but I don't learn very easily just reading from a book, etc. This class is kind of a nightmare for me.

Comment: @Monique: okay, there are essentially two approaches here: (1) don't mind the type when inserting in the vector, but take it into account when you sort them (like the solution of juanchopanza) or (2) detect the type at first input and write a template function with the correct type T, which you will use in the vector definition (thereafter you can use a simple std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater / std::lesser). (2) is preferrable in theory (you do data conversion only once, instead of `O(log n)` times for each element on average), but probably is a bit more complicated.

Comment: I'd rather do method 2 since my teacher mentioned in class that our program should be able to differentiate between types, but how do you detect the type at first input?? and how does that tie in with templates? it seems that if I were able to detect the type at first input, after that first input I could just create a vector with that type =\

Comment: @Monique: the "parsing" bit is explained in Matthieu's great answer (you can use his `guessType()` function at first input and then call the right templatized function with a switch on the return of the function). You can see how templates relates to type differentiation in the code I attached in the update of my answer

Comment: @akappa YES, that edit you did is something I mostly understand, it's perfect :D do you mind if I just ask a couple questions about it in chat with you? I'm kind of clogging up comments enough already, I feel

Comment: actually nvm, I have to go to work >.< thank you very much for your help, everyone, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects to this question: parsing & sorting.

- You can use *regular expressions* to check the user-input data-types.
- You can use `cin` to parse the data.

**First:** realise that you cannot *necessarily* know the *type* of your
users input until you have received all of it 
~eg: consider a list of user names :

```
728278243
390349346
495045594
elizabeth
```

Hence, best not to assume to know best about the incoming data (*can lead to a frustrating user-experience*) but instead, prefer to treat everything as potentially a string. Store all raw input as strings so you can output in same format as input.
you can use say, an enumerated type to switch inside a sort comparator
*or* consider using a `mutliset/multimap`. here you will be 
building an *ordered* set. so there is no need to sort.
NB: the complexity for constructing an ordered set of N elements *or*, for a single sort on N unsorted list elements, is roughly equivalent ~> NlogN

For your task-in-hand, it hardly matters but in reality depending upon upon how the list is used, one or other approach will be far more appropriate in performance terms.

If you have already used the likes of `std::vector` then `std::multimap` shouldn't be too scary. Loosely, it is an associated array of key-value pairs. the *multi* here meaning it can store multiple elements with the *same* key (which here, you want).

In this example i am using the *boost* regex library in order to determine some *funky* input data-types. 

(eg: `sudo apt-get install libboost-regex1.46-dev`)

This *regex* might seem arcane but there are many examples on the i/web for practically every conceivable pattern.
[*NB: C++11 regex is pretty-much a drop-in replacement for boost regex. ie: boost regex should be forward-compatible with the emerging C++11 standard*]

**blah.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>    
//NB: GNU gcc added *experimental support for regular expressions in TR1 v 4.3.0.
//    compile with:  -std=c++0x

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

//some example input data-types (perhaps notably missing a date!) 
const regex re_char("[^0-9]", regex_constants::extended); //non numeric chars
const regex re_digit("[[:digit:]]+", regex_constants::extended); //a string of only digits in range [0..9] ~ie: Z+
const regex re_xdigit("0[xX][[:xdigit:]]+", regex_constants::extended); //support hex iff starts with '0x' or '0X'
const regex re_float("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?", regex_constants::extended); //all kinds of numbers


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
    int i, countc=0;
    double d;
    string str;
    int element_count;    

    do
    {
        cout << "how many elements will there be? "; 
        if (cin >> element_count) break;
        cin.clear();
        cin >> str;
        cout << "\033[A\033[2K" << flush;
    }
    while(13);
    cin.ignore(128,'\n'); 

    multimap<double, string> list_num; 
    multimap<double, string> list_fp; 
    //NB: below, by way of example, construction using the 'greater<int>' comparison class achieves _descending_ order 
    multimap<int, string, greater<int> > list_int; 
    list<string> list_str; 

    for (int next=0; next < element_count; next++)
    {
        cout << "\033[A\033[2K" << flush;
        cout << "enter next element in list ["<< next+1 << "/" << element_count << "] : "; 
        getline (cin,str);

        if (regex_match(str, re_xdigit))
        {
            //see all about manipulators here:
            //http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/
            stringstream(str) >> hex >> i;            
            list_int.insert(pair<int, string>(i, str)); 
            list_num.insert(pair<double, string>(i, str)); 
        }
        else if (regex_match(str, re_digit))
        {
            stringstream(str) >> i;            
            list_int.insert(pair<int, string>(i, str));            
            list_num.insert(pair<double, string>(i, str)); 
        }
        else if (regex_match(str, re_float))
        {
            stringstream(str) >> d;    
            list_fp.insert(pair<double, string>(d, str));        
            list_num.insert(pair<double, string>(d, str)); 
        } 

        if (regex_match(str, re_char)) countc++;      
        list_str.push_back(str);
    }    

    cout << "\033[A\033[2K" << flush;

    cout << "input: unsorted list:" << endl;
    for (list<string>::iterator it=list_str.begin(); it!=list_str.end(); it++) 
        cout << *it << endl;

    if (list_int.size() == element_count)
    {
        cout << endl << "output: sorted list of Z+ types:" << endl;
        for (multimap<int, string>::iterator it=list_int.begin() ; it != list_int.end(); it++ )
            cout << (*it).second << endl;
    }
    else if (list_fp.size() == element_count)
    {
        cout << endl << "output: sorted list of fp types:" << endl;
        for (multimap<double, string>::iterator it=list_fp.begin() ; it != list_fp.end(); it++ )
            cout << (*it).second << endl;
    }
    else if (list_num.size() == element_count)
    {
        cout << endl << "output: sorted list of numeric types:" << endl;
        for (multimap<double, string>::iterator it=list_num.begin() ; it != list_num.end(); it++ )
            cout << (*it).second << endl;
    }
    else //output as sorted strings ~but in _descending_ order, using reverse iterator, by way of example
    {
        list_str.sort(); //but best to use list_str.sort(greater<string>()); with forward iterators
        cout << endl << "output: sorted list of " <<  (countc == element_count ? "non numeric char" : "string") << " types:" << endl;
        for (list<string>::reverse_iterator it=list_str.rbegin(); it!=list_str.rend(); ++it) 
            cout << *it << endl;        
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Example was compiled & run on Ubuntu. Commandline stuff:

```
$
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1 

$ g++ --pedantic -oblah blah.cpp -lboost_regex
$ ./blah
input: unsorted list:
4.77
2.0e+2
-.3
11
0x10

output: sorted list of numeric types:
-.3
4.77
11
0x10
2.0e+2
$
```

**NB:** This is example code:

- There are many optimisations that can be made here. You clearly
  don't *need* so many `stl` containers as i am using.
- I do not strictly deal with the direction of the sort (but show a couple of ways it may be achieved).
- It might also be nice to encapsulate the type-specific functionality 
  in C++ objects; have a base class & then derived classes for each *type* you wish 
  to support ~but this *homework* right? -so probably not worth going over-board then
  ;)