# Entering elements of unknown data type into vectors and passing to function templates

Tags: c++, vector, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inputting elements of unknown type into a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969040/inputting-elements-of-unknown-type-into-a-vector)

The program should get a list of elements of unknown type from user, be able to determine which type was used, be able to sort the elements, and print them back in the newly sorted order. The user will enter the number of elements as well as the elements, which must all be of the same type.

I am pretty new to programming and very new to templates and vectors. Any insight into what I've been doing wrong is appreciated.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int n;
    vector<int>Integers;
    vector<float>Floats;
    vector<char>Chars;
    vector<string>Strings;

    template <class T>

    //sorts vector elements
    void sort(const T &x)
    {
        char *ptr1,*ptr2;
        T tmp;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            ptr1=x[i];
            for (int j=i+1;j<=n;n++)
            {
                ptr2=x[j];
                if (tolower(ptr1)>tolower(ptr2))
                {
                    tmp=x[j];
                    x[j]=x[i];
                    x[i]=tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    //prints vector in ascending order
    void ascend(const T &x)
    {
        for (int z=0;z<n;z++)
        {
            cout<<x[z];
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    //prints vector in descending order
    void descend(const T &x)
    {
        for (int z=n;z>=0;z--)
        {
            cout<<x[z];
        }

    }

    template <class T>
    //prints in both orders
    void both(const T &x)
    {
        for (int z=0;z<n;z++)
        {
            cout<<x[z];
        }
        for (int z=n;z>=0;z--)
        {
            cout<<x[z];
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        int x=0, y=0;
        string input;
        cout<<"Number of elements: "<<endl;
        cin>>n;
        cout<<"Enter elements: "<<endl;
        cin>>input;
        //determines data type of first element inputed
        for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
        {
            //int
            if (input[i]>='0'&&input[i]<='9')
                x=1;
            //float
            else if (input[i]=='.')
                    {
                        x=2;
                        i=input.size();
                    }
            //char
            else if (input[i]>='A'&&input[i]<='z')
                x=3;
            //string
            if(input[i+1]>='A'&&input[i+1]<='z')
                {
                    x=4;
                    i=input.size();
                }
        }

        //populates vectors of various data types of size n
        switch(x)
        {
            //int 
            case 1: 
            {
                int a=1;
                //creates vector of of size n+1
                Integers.resize(n+1);
                //concatenates first element
                for (int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
                {
                    a=(a*10)+input[i];
                }
                Integers[0]=a;
                //adds in rest of elements
                for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                    cin>>Integers[i];
                sort(Integers);
                break;
            }
            //float
            case 2: 
            {
                float b=1;
                Floats.resize(n+1);
                for (int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
                {
                    if(input[i]!='.')
                        b=(b*10)+input[i];
                    else
                    {   
                        i++;
                        for(int x=10,i;i<input.size();x*10,i++)
                        {
                            b+=input[i]/x;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Floats[0]=b;
                for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                    cin>>Floats[i];
                sort(&Floats);
                break;
            }
            //char
            case 3:
            {   
                Chars.resize(n+1);
                Chars[0]=input[0];
                for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                    cin>>Chars[i];
                sort(Chars);
                break;
            //string
            }
            case 4: 
            {
                Strings.resize(n+1);
                Strings[0]=input;
                for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                    cin>>Strings[i];
                sort(Strings);
                break;
            }
        }
        cout<<"Ascending (1), Descending (2), or Both (3)? ";
        cin>>y;

        //determines what vector is to be printed out and in what format
        switch(y)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                switch(x)
                {
                    case 1: ascend(Integers); break;
                    case 2: ascend(Floats); break;
                    case 3: ascend(Chars); break;
                    case 4: ascend(Strings); break;
                }
            }
            case 2:
            {
                switch(x)
                {
                    case 1: descend(Integers); break;
                    case 2: descend(Floats); break;
                    case 3: descend(Chars); break;
                    case 4: descend(Strings); break;
                }
            }
            case 3:
            {
                switch(x)
                {
                    case 1: both(Integers); break;
                    case 2: both(Floats); break;
                    case 3: both(Chars); break;
                    case 4: both(Strings); break;
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How does a user give a list of "unknown" types?  If the user is interacting with the system via the command line, all data will come in the format of strings.  Granted, you could extract other types from the input stream (floats, integers, etc.), but that seems to be not exactly what is being asked for.

Comment: [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/any.html) is supposed to be a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is homework, you should be using std::sort - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort